# How do I Inner Join users table with followed users posts?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve the posts from the people the current user is following along with their details. I've been researching at it seems a join is the right way to do it but I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Here is my code

```
$queryfeed = "SELECT posts.user_id, posts.body, posts.image, posts.has_image 
FROM posts, follows WHERE posts.user_id =  follows.leader_id 
AND follows.follower_id =$user_id INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id 
= follows.leader_id";

$resultfeed = $db->query($queryfeed);
if($resultfeed->num_rows > 0) {
    while( $rowfeed = $resultfeed->fetch_assoc() ) {       
        if($rowfeed['posts.has_image'] == 1) {
    ?>
            <article class="post">
                <div class="post-head cf">
                    <a class="userpic" href=""><img src="<?php echo $userpic ?>" alt="<?php echo $rowfeed['users.username'] ?>"></a>
                    <a href="" class="username">
                        <?php echo $rowfeed[users.'username']; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <img src="users/user_<?php echo $rowfeed['posts.user_id'] ?>/posts/<?php echo $rowfeed['posts.image']; ?>" alt="">
                <div class="post-body">
                    <div class="post-options">
                        <a class="likes" href="">2 likes</a>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <a class="username" href="">
                                <?php echo $rowfeed['users.username'] ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php echo $rowfeed['posts.body'] ?>
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="cf">
                        <a class="like hide-text" href="javascript:;">Like This Post</a>
                        <form action="" class="comment">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a comment">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>

   <?php } else { ?>
```

My tables look like this

```
users
user_id | username | avatar

posts
post_id | user_id | body | image | has_image

follows
leader_id | follower_id
```

Comment: Select * from posts p inner join users u on p.user_id = u.user_id where... ur criteria. That's a simple inner join

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi 
 
Correct me if I am wrong but what you are saying would just be for the users posts wouldn't it? I am trying to get the posts from the people the user follows, and get their avatar and username to display along with the pos

Comment: It'll get everything from the posts as well as users table. So you can output that data as you normally would any row.

Comment: Basically, you have to join where your criteria matches in both tables you wish to fetch data from.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi sorry would you mind actually writing down the query? I don't understand how it would check to see if the user is following them.

Comment: Andy has provided a suitable answer. I was just pointing u in the right direction with first comment.

Comment: What do you mean by this? `I am trying to retrieve the posts from the people the current user is following along with their details.` details of the people being followed?

Comment: @barudo I got the query working to retrieve the posts that the user is following, but the posts table doesn't contain their username/avatar. So when I query for them I get the image and body content of the post but not their picture or username

Comment: @barudo thats why I was trying to join the users table to compare the leader_id to the user_id but from the answers the post is getting I might be doing this wrong....

Comment: Still struggling? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your original query, I see that you are only interested in the posts' data (not that of the user who posted it). I assume that $user_id holds the id of the current user, i.e. a value that is also used as follower_id. If this is the case, the query gets easier:

```sql
SELECT p.user_id, p.body, p.image, p.has_image
FROM followers f INNER JOIN posts p ON f.leader_id = p.user_id and f.follower_id = $user_id
```

If you are interested also in the poster's user data, change the query as follows:

```sql
SELECT p.user_id, p.body, p.image, p.has_image, u.username, u.avatar
FROM follows f
  INNER JOIN posts p ON f.leader_id = p.user_id and f.follower_id = $user_id
  INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: This is similar to the original query I had before trying to do a join where I get the posts from the people the user is following. But the thing is the posts don't contain the username and picture ('avatar') from the person that wrote the posts. That is where I'm stuck

Comment: there's one difference: the condition here is `ON p.user_id = u.user_id`, which connects the poster's user_id to the user's user_id. So it should give you the user who did the respective post. (Sorry - you also connected it to f.leader_id, so it should be the same)...

Comment: YESSSSS this is what I was looking for! My old query worked the only thing is I had user_id = leader_id instead of post_id Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have no access to a computer right now but it seems that your SQL-Query has some errors. Check out my corrected version:

```
SELECT posts.user_id, posts.body, posts.image, posts.has_image FROM posts
INNER JOIN follows ON posts.user_id = follows.follower_id
WHERE follows.leader_id=$user_id;
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work :/ Also I don't see where the call to the users table is since it is using users.user_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    posts.user_id, posts.body, posts.image, posts.has_image
    authors.avatar, authors.username
FROM
    posts
LEFT JOIN
    users as authors
ON
    authors.user_id=posts.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    follows
ON
    follows.leader_id=authors.user_id
WHERE
    follows.follower_id={$user_id}
```

Using LEFT JOINs ONLY....

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that the current user.user_id is 1 and followers are user.user_id 2,3, and 4

I would think that we need to meet the following criteria right?

`posts.user_id = follows.follower_id
follows.leader_id = $user_id`

So the query would need to be something like this right?

`SELECT *
FROM posts
INNER JOIN follows
ON posts.user_id = follows.follower_id
INNER JOIN users
ON follows.leader_id = $user_id`

Here are mocked examples of the tables

`=== users ===
user_id | username | avatar
1         current
2         fake1
3         fake2
4         fake3`


`=== posts ===
post_id | user_id | body | image | has_image
1          2
2          2
3          3
4          3
5          4
6          4`


`=== follows ===
leader_id | follower_id
1            2
1            3
1            4`

Does that make sense? Because the current user ($user_id) is the leader of the followers, so the follower_id's would need to be the users of the posts if you want the **posts of the followers** not the post of the leader...